# is it possible to have only header file in C without source file

Tags: c, compilation, header

I would like to write a C library with fast access by including just header files without using compiled library.  For that I have included my code directly in my header file.

The header file contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef INC_TEST_H_
#define INC_TEST_H_

void test(){
    printf("hello\n");
}

#endif
```

My program doesn't compile because I have multiple reference to function `test()`.  If I had a correct source file with my header it works without error.

Is it possible to use only header file by including code inside in a C app?

Comment: Access will not be faster because you have compiled header files in C. In  all cases, a function call must be made.

Comment: Yes, but contrary to a function call in a library, a function call in the code itself can be "optimized" by the compilator (inlining, and maybe some other thing i don't know).

Comment: @Tom's, I agree, thx for your input.

Answer (score 6):

Including code in a header is generally a really bad idea.

If you have `file1.c` and `file2.c`, and in each of them you include your `coded.h`, then at the link part of the compilation, there will be 2 test functions with global scope (one in `file1.c` and the other one in `file2.c`).

You can use the word "static" in order to say that the function will be restricted so it is only visible in the `.c` file which includes `coded.h`, but then again, it's a bad idea.

Last but not least: how do you intend to make a library without a `.so`/`.a` file? This is not a library; this is copy/paste code directly in your project.

And when a bug is found in your "library", you will be left with no solution apart correcting your code, redispatch it in every project, and recompile every project, missing the very point of a dynamic library: The ability to "just" correct the library without touching every program using it.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to create a "library" which is strictly source code that gets `#incude`d as necessary, rather than compiled separately and linked.

As you have discovered, this is not easy when you're dealing with functions - the compiler complains of multiple definitions (you will have the same problem with object definitions).

You have a couple of  options at this point.

You could declare the function `static`:

```
static void test( void )
{
  ...
}
```

The `static` keyword limits the function's visibility to the current translation unit, so you don't run into multiple definition errors at link time.  It means that each translation unit is creating its own separate "instance" of the function, leading to a bit of code bloat and slightly longer build times. If you can live with that, this is the easiest solution.

You could use a macro in place of a function:

```
#define TEST() (printf( "hello\n" ))
```

except that *macros are not functions* and do not behave like functions.  While macro-based "libraries" do exist, they are not trivial to implement correctly and require quite a bit of thought. Remember that macro arguments are not evaluated, they're just expanded in place, which can lead to problems if you pass expressions with side effects.  The classic example is:

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))
...
y = SQUARE(z++);
```

`SQUARE(z++)` expands to `((z++)*(z++))`, which leads to undefined behavior.

Separate compilation is a Good Thing, and you should not try to avoid it.  Doing *everything* in one source file is not scalable, and leads to maintenance headaches.

Comment: Good idea to use macros!!

Answer (score 2):

> My program do not compiled because I have multiple reference to test() function

That is because the .h file with the function is included and compiled in multiple C source files. As a result, the linker encounters the function with global scope multiple times.

You could have defined the function as `static`, which means it will have scope only for the curent compilation unit, so:

```
static void test()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```